# How to increase opacity in javascript?

Tags: javascript, opacity

I would expect to be able to use

```
element.style.opacity += 0.1;
```

or

```
element.style.opacity = element.style.opacity + 0.1;
```

but this does not work. The opacity does not change. If I set the opacity to a static value, like

```
element.style.opacity = 0.5;
```

it does work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Curious as to why this is being rated down?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`element.style.opacity` (assuming it is defined at all) will be a String, not a Number.

```
"0.1" + 0.1 === "0.10.1"
```

You probably want:

```
element.style.opacity = parseFloat(element.style.opacity) + 0.1;
```

Answer (score 4):

It occurred to me that you can actually decrease the opacity by a string factor, as following:

```
element.style.opacity -= '0.1';
```

And that will work just fine, but not the opposite since the operator += tries to append to the resulting string. Increment can however be achieved by doing

```
element.style.opacity -= '-0.1';
```

Which will increment it as wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following, which assigns a predefined value for `opacity` if it's not already defined:

```
// using a simple onclick for demo purposes
t.onclick = function(){
    var opacity = this.style.opacity;
    this.style.opacity = opacity ? (parseFloat(opacity) + 0.1) : 0.2;
};​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r6BSU/).

This seems to be necessary because the value doesn't seem to be incremented if the `opacity` isn't already defined in the in-line `style` attribute. If that's where yours *is* defined then this approach may not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make keyframes setup in css and add the id or class to the element

```
Example for calling a keyframe:
.myElement{
position:absolute;
background:blue;
-webkit-animation:KeyframeName 1s linear infinite;
}

Example for a keyframe:
@-webkit-keyframes KeyframeName {
0%{style code here, example: opacity:1;}
100%{style code here, example: opacity:0;}
}
```

The only down sides are:
- you have to make a keyframe setup for all browsers.
- on mobile devices it takes alot of power, meaning you page becomes un-touchable or onclickable. And makes it hard to use many keyframes at once.

Or

Try making a function in javascript and put this code in it:

```
var OpacityValue = 1;
function OpacityChange(){
    if(OpacityValue == 0.0){
        Opacity = 0.0;
        clearInterval(TimerName);
     }
     else if(OpacityValue > 0){
        OpacityValue += -0.1;
     }
     yourElement.style.opacity = OpacityValue;
}
```

Launch this function with a timer an you got you opacity that will stop when its at a value of 0.0
Don't forget to place a var TimerName ; as global, otherwise you cant stop the timer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use also [`.toString();`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp) method